# Conditional linear fitting with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, broom

I am trying to do linear fitting in a  grouped data.

However, I also want to add some conditions throughout the fitting but failed to do that when I subset some conditions.

```
set.seed(183)
library(dplyr)
V <- rep(seq(1,8),3)
value = c(c(sort(runif(5,0.001,1)),rep(0,3)),c(sort(runif(5,0.001,1)),rep(0,2),runif(1,0.001,1)),c(sort(runif(5,0.001,1)),rep(0,2),runif(1,0.001,1)))
group=rep(letters[1:3],each=8)

df <- data.frame(group,V,value)

#    > df
#   group V      value
#1      a 1 0.15087459
#2      a 2 0.35408406
#3      a 3 0.47339320
#4      a 4 0.67614665
#5      a 5 0.98273932
#6      a 6 0.00000000
#7      a 7 0.00000000
#8      a 8 0.00000000
#9      b 1 0.32821476
#10     b 2 0.35737009
#11     b 3 0.58821689
#12     b 4 0.81088053
#13     b 5 0.99122633
#14     b 6 0.00000000
#15     b 7 0.00000000
#16     b 8 0.03697432
#17     c 1 0.12940226
#18     c 2 0.41918905
#19     c 3 0.66020739
#20     c 4 0.84124155
#21     c 5 0.95052213
#22     c 6 0.00000000
#23     c 7 0.00000000
#24     c 8 0.15071444
```

My conditions inside of each groups are

1) if all last 3 `value==0` fit only when `V>=4&V<=5`

2)if any last 2 `value>0` fit only when `V>=7`.

Here is the function I wrote to do this operation

```
   get_slope <- function(df){
  if (tail(df$value,3)==0)
    slp = coef(lm(value~V, data=subset(df,V>=4&V<=5)))[2]
    else 
    if (any(tail(df$value,3)>=0))
        slp = coef(lm(value ~ V, data=subset(df,V>=7)))[2]
    return(slp)
  }

df_slope <- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  do(.,slope=get_slope(df))

Warning messages:
1: In if (tail(df$value, 3) == 0) slp = coef(lm(value ~ V, data = subset(df,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (tail(df$value, 3) == 0) slp = coef(lm(value ~ V, data = subset(df,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (tail(df$value, 3) == 0) slp = coef(lm(value ~ V, data = subset(df,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Finally I want to get slope value in each group.

is there an easy way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `tail(df$value,3)==0` will give 3 T/F values. I swap it around in the function below, and use split and plyr::ldply instead of dplyr.

```
df1<-split(df, df$group)
get_slope <- function(df){
  if (any(!tail(df$value,3)==0)) coef(lm(value ~ V, data=subset(df,V>=7)))[2]
  else  coef(lm(value~V, data=subset(df,V>=4&V<=5)))[2]
}
library(plyr)
ldply(df1, get_slope)

  .id          V
1   a 0.06940913
2   b 0.20794964
3   c 0.84607397
```

dplyr method as requested:

```
df_slope <- df %>% 
               group_by(group) %>% 
               do(.,slope=get_slope(.))

df_slope$slope <- df_slope$slope %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
df_slope

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

   group      slope
  (fctr)      (dbl)
1      a 0.06940913
2      b 0.20794964
3      c 0.84607397
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why we cannot do it in dplyr chain?

Comment: Of course you can. Just beware that pipes may not be as efficient as an as the ldply function.

Comment: If so would you add dplyr way also as an answer to your post?

Comment: dplyr option added. Personally prefer the more straightforward ldply.

Comment: The `do` option doesn't have to be quite so complicated.  Use `do(data.frame(slope = get_slope(.)))` or end the chain with `%>% unnest` from tidyr to reproduce the `ldply` results.

Comment: Thanks for the `tidyr::unnest` tip. I much prefer the `plyr::ldply` method over relying on pipes and group_by...

Answer (score 1):

**what come to my thought is to loop all level and apply the function.**

1.set a array to receive all result

```
    slp = c()
```

2.Loop all level in the group and do the action if the condition is satisfied.

```
 for( group in unique(df$group)){
     if(sum(tail(df$value[which(df$group==group)],3) == c(0,0,0))==3){
       slp = c(slp,coef(lm(value~V, data=subset(df,V>=4&V<=5)))[2])
      }else if(any(tail(df$value[which(df$group==group)],2)>=0)){
   slp = c(slp, coef(lm(value ~ V, data=subset(df,V>=7)))[2])
     }}
```

3.Print the result

```
slp
         a          b          c 
0.06448301 0.55057826 0.55057826
```

My solution might not be easy as expected but should be easy to understand, I hope it could be helpful.